# How do I load models in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, models

How do I load them from a route, controller or `app::before`? Do I `require` the file or do Laravel have a function for it? I can't find any documents on this issue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are you exactly doing and where do you have problem - it should be as easy as Model::method() since everything in Laravel is autoloaded... also remember to dump autoloader from time to time with `composer dump-autoload`.